# How can i display HTML elements in gtkmm3 on Windows 10 and installing libraries using msys2?

Tags: c++, msys2, renderer, gtkmm3

I want to create this application in which I need a viewer for HTML and I've been trying for a long time but I just can't seem to get it.

I tried using webkitgtk2 but then i saw this post on Reddit in which it said you can't install webgitgtk2 on windows so I also began to try libgtkhtml but the installation just gives an error. I, however was expecting the application to pop up but it didn't because of installation issues.

For webkitgtk2 I tried using
'''
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-webkitgtk
'''
in msys2 but that raised an error message that the package didn't exist so when I switched to libgtkhtml, I tried:
"pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libgtkhtml" in msys2 but that raised the same error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Indeed it seems that MSYS2 doesn't have those libraries packaged ATM. But the fact that you tried to install them like this is suspicious. All compilers and libraries you install should normally be prefixed with `mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-` or something like it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I forgot